# Intellij IDEA. Generate javadoc as jar archive

Tags: jar, intellij-idea, javadoc

How should I generate javadoc for my project (class library) as jar archive using Intellij IDEA 11?

Is there any way to generate javadoc within generating artifact (jar archive) for my project?

Answer (score 3):

1) Tools | Generate JavaDoc. You can find more detail in [generate-javadoc-dialog](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generate-javadoc-dialog.html).

2) run "jar cf yourJarName * " on the directory which contains the JavaDoc you just generate.